# Hashcat brute-force is not working properly

Tags: brute-force, hashcat

My hash (MD5): d0bae1f4cb8fc6b2f0d56c8cb7fad99a

In string: 599142142

Command:

```
hashcat -a3 -m0 d0bae1f4cb8fc6b2f0d56c8cb7fad99a ?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d -O
```

Result:

```
Session..........: hashcat                       
Status...........: Exhausted
Hash.Name........: MD5
Hash.Target......: d0bae1f4cb8fc6b2f0d56c8cb7fad99a
Time.Started.....: Mon Nov  9 10:36:45 2020 (4 secs)
Time.Estimated...: Mon Nov  9 10:36:49 2020 (0 secs)
Guess.Mask.......: ?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d [9]
Guess.Queue......: 1/1 (100.00%)
Speed.#2.........:   259.0 MH/s (0.46ms) @ Accel:16 Loops:7 Thr:512 Vec:1
Recovered........: 0/1 (0.00%) Digests
Progress.........: 1000000000/1000000000 (100.00%)
Rejected.........: 0/1000000000 (0.00%)
Restore.Point....: 1000000/1000000 (100.00%)
Restore.Sub.#2...: Salt:0 Amplifier:994-1000 Iteration:0-7
Candidates.#2....: 976488164 -> 688749494
```

Mask is correct, Hash mode is correct so why it's not cracking?

For example if I specify first 5 digits in my mask, then it's working:

```
hashcat -a3 -m0 d0bae1f4cb8fc6b2f0d56c8cb7fad99a 59914?d?d?d?d -O
```

Result:

```
d0bae1f4cb8fc6b2f0d56c8cb7fad99a:599142142       
                                                 
Session..........: hashcat
Status...........: Cracked
Hash.Name........: MD5
Hash.Target......: d0bae1f4cb8fc6b2f0d56c8cb7fad99a
Time.Started.....: Mon Nov  9 10:40:06 2020 (0 secs)
Time.Estimated...: Mon Nov  9 10:40:06 2020 (0 secs)
Guess.Mask.......: 59914?d?d?d?d [9]
Guess.Queue......: 1/1 (100.00%)
Speed.#2.........:  3346.7 kH/s (0.13ms) @ Accel:32 Loops:1 Thr:512 Vec:1
Recovered........: 1/1 (100.00%) Digests
Progress.........: 10000/10000 (100.00%)
Rejected.........: 0/10000 (0.00%)
Restore.Point....: 0/10000 (0.00%)
Restore.Sub.#2...: Salt:0 Amplifier:0-1 Iteration:0-1
Candidates.#2....: 599145234 -> 599149494
```

What's the problem? Help please.

P.S. hashcat version v6.1.1

Comment: I'm running into the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug with version v6.1.1, I was able to reproduce it and after updating to 6.2.1 it works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you're asking why you don't see the a password, What I do is apply --show at the end of the command.

[hashcat -a3 -m0 d0bae1f4cb8fc6b2f0d56c8cb7fad99a 59914?d?d?d?d --show ]

Applying this will show as:
d0bae1f4cb8fc6b2f0d56c8cb7fad99a:599142142

Comment: adding --show shows hash in potfile which already was cracked